# How to properly create a tree in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I came across this problem at work recently, and couldn't figure out how to accomplish it with Scala.  I'm using the play framework, so I have access to the JSON library.  I'm new to Scala, and would like to know how to accomplish this specific task.  The sample data is an example of what the real data looks like.

In the end, I wasn't able to figure this out and instead parsed the data in a PHP consumer of this Scala API.  I'd love to change that :)

Thanks!

---

Given the following tupple:

```
(("GET","a/b/c"),("POST","a/c/d"),("POST","f/e/x/r"),("GET","a/c/f/f"))
```

Produce the following JSON:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "GET" : "GET"
      }
    },

    "c": {
      "d": {
        "POST": "POST"
      },

      "f": {
        "f": {
          "GET": "GET"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "f": {
    "e": {
      "x": {
        "r": {
          "POST": "POST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code so far and where did you get stuck? Stack Overflow is not a place to ask someone else to write code for you.

Comment: That's reasonable enough.  Unfortunately, I never committed my attempts.  I'm having difficulty understanding conceptually how to "reach in" to multi-dimensional maps or arrays.  I'm not really looking for somebody to write code for me, I'm trying to figure out the scala paradigm for what seems like a fairly straight-forward operation in other languages.

I've added the php code I used to make this in the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you probably don't want your data to be in a tuple. Tuples are for holding different type of values in a statically fixed number. You'll be better off with `List[(String, String)]` which allows you to add as many routes as you want (while your example is stuck with 4)

Next, you need to recursively nest objects, if you have the different segments in your path. This can be done quite easily with `foldRight`:

```
def nestedObjects(inside: JsObject, nesters: Seq[String]): JsObject = 
  nesters.foldRight(inside)((nester, in) => Json.obj(nester -> in)
```

Now, we need to extract that list of nesters from the path you are given, and define the inside object:

```
def treatPair(method: String, path: String): JsObject = {
  val nesters = path.split("/")
  val inside = Json.obj(method -> method)
  nestedObjects(inside, nesters)
}
```

Now, we're left to merging all results, for which play-json already have a method: `deepMerge`

```
def reduceList(routes: List[(String, String)]): JsObject = {
  routes.map {
    case (method, path) => treatPair(method, path) //apply treatPair on each pair
  }.fold(Json.obj())(_ deepMerge _) //merge them two-by-two
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!   I think this will require some analysis on my part to completely understand.  But I dig it.  Thanks!